# What is the correct syntax to define specializations of template method

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, template-specialization

Say I declared a class with a template method.

```
class MyClass {
    ...
    template<typename T> void myMethod(const T& obj);
}
```

I have defined a generic version of the method

```
template<typename T>
void MyClass::myMethod(const T& obj) { .... }
```

and want to define several specializations for various types. What is the correct syntax? VS2013 compiler does not seem to approve my attempts.

```
template<>
void MyClass::myMethod<int>(const int &) {....}

or

template<int>
void MyClass::myMethod(const int &) { .... }
```

Comment: Your syntax seems correct ([live demo](http://ideone.com/VkbhO3)), but you forgot the semicolon at the end of the class definition.

Comment: Right you are. I figured that my problems come from an attempt to provide specializations that in certain cases instead of "const T&" use "const T* &" parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first syntax is ok, as a specialization. The second is wrong as it is defining a `template<int>` while `myMethod` is declared as a `template<typename>`. But keep in mind that a specialization isn't needed at all, an overload is just fine, like

```
class MyClass {
   void myMethod(const int& obj) { ... }
   // ... more overloads
};
```

Of course, if you need to separate declarations from definitions (which I avoid for templates), this leads to more code duplication. Depending on type, this way you may also enforce call by value, e.g.

```
void myMethod(bool obj) { ... }
```

which does not apply to your specializations.